# File not found on Android Device

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an error here:

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("hscore.json");
```

Showing that it can't be found:

```
...
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: hscore.json (Local)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
...
```

It works on my Desktop, but fails like this on my Android Phone.

I use Android Studio, where I keep the file in the assets folder which is in the android folder.
[image]

I have no idea why it can't find it on the android?

**Update:** I don't know what happened in meantime, but now it highlights this line of code after throwing the same error:

```
String s = file.readString();
```

It can read .txt files and other files I'm using just fine, seems the .json file is the problem for android?

---

Until this is resolved, I'm using Preferences to save data there, rather than the whole class in .json

Comment: try Gdx.files.classpath("hscore.json"); for assets folder files

Comment: @Vickyexpert Tried it all, doesn't work still.

Comment: assign full path like file:///android_asset/hscore.json

Comment: Your code is correct. it should work if everything works properly. It's probably a buildscript problem or something similar. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project first if you did not do this yet.

Comment: @p.streef Did that already and again, still crashes and says the file was not found.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of the file in the correct folder? It could be something silly like case sensitivity (which windows does not have, but android does).

Comment: @p.streef Updated the question.

Comment: The file cannot be found exception is thrown during "read" because it does not actually check if the file exists before that. If you were to call "fille.exists()" it would return false.

Is this the only file that has issues, or can you reproduce it with a file in for instance the "Sound" folder?

Comment: @p.streef The sounds and other files work just fine, for example I load the sounds like: coinSnd = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Sound/coin.ogg"));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114598/discussion-between-p-streef-and-matta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a chat with [p.streef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603511/p-streef) This question has come to a closure, sorta.

1) I created a new test.txt file and it worked fine reading that.

Maybe then the .json file itself was a real issue?

2) But then I renamed it to text.json, and afterwards back to hscore.json

It worked fine in both cases when opening and reading the file.

I had no idea why the initial file .json was not readable?

3) I also killed and restarted my android studio in meantime because it froze at a point when building my project.

After all of this the problem of file not being found was resolved by itself.

Anyway then I realized that the file is not writable since internal files are read-only.

I decided to stick then with the Preferences as the final solution.